# Delete Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am working with extremely large datasets, so I need to remove any intermediate dataframe. How do I ensure that any dataframe that I don't need is deleted from memory/disk?

Comment: Did you try setting the reference to None?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `spark.catalog.clearCache`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html